# Initializing a Global Variable Memory Layout

Tags: c

I know that when you declare a global uninitialized variable in C that it lives in the .bss segment. But what happens if you take that value and set it equal to something in a function? Does it move to the stack segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stays exactly where it is; you just changed its value. The `bss` section it was placed in is just because global variables are initialized to zero by default, so including them directly in your executable file would be a waste of (disk) space. After program initialization, your `bss` variables can quite happily have non-zero values.